# How get JSON string from XML string using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to convert XML string to C# object, I have json string acle in xml tag, as shown below,

```
<message> <data:gcm xmlns:data=\"google:mobile:data\">{\"message_type\":\"ack\",\"from\":\"sdhad4asd4a-sdasd45ds\",\"message_id\":\"-something\"}</data:gcm> </message>
```

I want json string from data tag I just want this string from above xml,

> {\"message_type\":\"ack\",\"from\":\"sdhad4asd4a-sdasd45ds\",\"message_id\":\"-something\"}

So how can I get this using c#.?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the value of the element in the XML is already JSON, then it sounds like you're *really* just asking "How do I get the value of a specific element in XML" right? Nothing JSON-specific. I suggest you read a LINQ to XML tutorial.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes you are right I want value of XML element, Let me check with suggestion, and thank you for quick response. appreciated.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading some LINQ to XML documents I got the solution which is like below,

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Parse(msg.ToString());

var result = xdoc.Element("message").Descendants();

var myString = result.FirstOrDefault().Value; //This will out given json string
```

Again Thank you @JonSkeet for your suggestion.!